# Magento shopwide price reduction without needing to add a catalog price rule

Tags: magento

I have added a shopwide catalog price rule of 20% on all products. This seems to work. However, for some reason after a re-index I have to reset this price rule time and time again. As most of my shop runs with automatic imports and cron jobs - I would somehow like to hardcode this rule in. So I don't need to reset the rule every time.

Also the fact that my price is tagged as special price is something I would like to get rid of. The price is just the initial price minus 20%. This is not a special offer - it's just the price how I want to offer it to my customers.

Up till now I haven't found a solution to my problem - or where to start. Suggestions would very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Use shopping cart price rules

> admin/promo_quote/

And set the discount of 20% there. It will apply to the cart and you won't have to the catalog price rules every time.

If you need more fine-grain control, check out:

> http://www.amasty.com ( unaffiliated but happy with dozens of their extensions )